# Merge rows in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, rows

How do I merge multiple rows with same ID number into a single row in SQL Server?

[image: See image of the table before and after]

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't quite make sense. Naively I'd say you could group by ID and Event, but that's not true. YOu could do ID, and Event, but what value do you want from the other days for that ID? Also, why does CR1 contain no data in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you will need to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT ID, Event = MAX(Event), Location = MAX(Location), 
           Cr = MAX(Cr), Cr0 = MAX(CR0),  .. . 
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) statement.

In your case, `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY ID`

Comment: I received this error "Column 'table.Event' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Try adding `Event` To your group by. Also, you can't do `select *`. You'll have to specify the columns you want, and any aggregates